# Is it possible to use two different css styles for the same theme in two stores

Tags: css, magento

we are using the same theme for two magento stores.

Is it possible to change css styles differently for both stores?
They are in the same root folder but using different domains.

For example if I change the color for the navigation, it will change the color in both stores.

Is there any good explanation how to do this?

Thank you

Comment: you have one css for two stores...Right?

Comment: Yes. But maybe I can make two?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, we have store specific layout handle. So you can use the same handle in `local.xml` to add different CSS in the same theme.

```
<STORE_custom1>
  <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/store_custom.css</stylesheet></action>
  </reference>
</STORE_custom1>

<STORE_custom2>
  <reference name="head">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/store_custom2.css</stylesheet></action>
  </reference>
</STORE_custom2>
```

Here custom1 and custom2 store view code.

You can check all the appied handles using the below code:

```
print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
```